# make tab keyboard button jump from right to left

Tags: java, jtextfield

CASE: 
create jpanel
add a few textbox horizontally
set panel to setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)

PROBLEM:
when running, focus on one textbox and press tab button , the focus will jump from left to right , how do i make it jump from right to left?

FOLLOW UP: 
say I want one component to be skipped, I can catch the on focus event for this component, but can i issue an automated additional tab click to jump to the next component ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FocusTraversalPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html).
Here's an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FocusTraversalExample.htm).